# Number of edition in git repository

Tags: git, git-log

Please, how can i compute the total number of line edited in git repository ? i'm trying this line commande:

> `git log --oneline --shortstat`

but it returns the number of edition per files. How can i obatain the total number ? the addition of all edition ? How can i obtain the total line (inserted+deleted) in git repository ?

Comment: by edition do you mean commit? Do you want the sum of all edited lines for each commit?

Comment: the sum of all edited lines (for each commit) in all git repository

Comment: I think that you have to do it yourself, parsing the output `git log --shortstat` and do the maths

Comment: If i know how can i do it alone, i don't ask :)

Comment: Sure, but it's a script to write, and maybe nobody will write it for you (I won't, I'm at work). Or maybe not.

Comment: There are not a commande line directly ?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want

```
git diff --shortstat
```

If you want the total lines changed between two commits simply use

```
git diff --shortstat $commit1 $commit2
```

---

However your question is not completely precise.

Giving the following situation:

```
     ,-- a -- b --, 
o---x              m --o
     `-- c -- d --'
```

Starting at some commit `x` someone adds 100 lines in commit `a` and then deletes the same commits in commit `b`. Someone else adds 10 lines at commit `c` and deletes the same 10 line at commit `d`. Afterwards `d` and `b` are merged in commit `m`. In this case `x` and `m` contains exactly the same files.

What would you expect to be the number of changed lines?

- 0 - because the files are still the same?
- 220 - because adding all individual changes would result in this number?
- 200 or 20 - because those are the changes on each path?
- something different?

Try to answer this question for you.

If you come up with `0` use `git diff --shortstat`.

If you come up with `220` use `git log --shortstat` and add the values manually.

Comment: If you do not specify any arguments it will work on the diff between you working tree and the index, which is likely to be empty. Use `git help diff` to learn how to specify what you want.

Comment: If i give the last commit with the first commit, i obtain the total line edited in all git repository ?

Comment: you get the lines differing between the first and the last commit. which is not necessarily the same as the total lines edited.